# Apache - using .htaccess redirect to root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with the **.htaccess** file. I have it configured in this way.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?controller=$1 [L]
```

Every time I access `http://localhost/mvc3/contacto/` I'm accessing  `http://localhost/mvc3/index.php?controller=contacto`, up there it is correct but if the friendly URL I remove the final character `/` *(http://localhost/mvc3/contacto)* it returns me to the root page (wampserver server).

Here is explained in video of the problem, what would be happening?

Video ▶️ http://recordit.co/FfXHww1xCv

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1 [L]
```

Remove slash from the rewrite rule and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

may below changes in .htaccess will be helpful for you

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

</IfModule>
```

Comment: okay, can you please share more detail about php application like which framework are you using or not, etc.
which server do you have?

Comment: yes, you can download here: https://filenurse.com/download/eed0df86b4577e05fa50b3b2394673df.html